# Изменение маркеров в маркированных списках HTML

Tags: html, css

Как изменить цвет и размер маркера в одном из списков, если их несколько на странице? Как сделать маркер-картинку?

Answer (score 2):

```
li{
color: red; // цвет. вместе с текстом, ага
font-size: 200%; // размер. с текстом же
list-style-image: url(myImage.gif); // картинка
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Lists: [раз](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) и [два](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/list.php).

Answer (score 0):

что бы поменять цвет маркеров одного списка используем "точечный удар" =)

```
ul {color: green;} /* Все списки зеленые */
ul.one {color: red;} /* <ul class="one"> - красный */
```

Маркер картинка - как писал ling [link text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32626/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-html/32628), но мне больше нравиться так:

```
li {
     padding-left: 15px; /* расстояние от начала маркера до начало текста */
     background: url(../images/img.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* поигравшись с "нулями" можно выставить маркер как нужно */
}
```